# Magento 2 custom product attribute not showing images in frontend

Tags: magento2

I have the following code fetching custom attribute which is a textarea attribute

```
$_product->getCustomAttribute('size_guide')->getValue();
```

However, everything displays perfectly except the media url. It appears to be broken.

```
<img src="{{media url=" wysiwyg="" hoodies.jpg"}}"="" alt="">
```

Comment: can you add more code? what is custom attribute type? where do you want to display it?

Answer (score 1):

`wysiwyg` enabled attribute needs to be filtered and processed first. You can use helper `Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output` to do this. For example,

```
echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getSizeGuide(), 'size_guide');
```

Comment: Works well on Pagebuilder attribute too,Magento 2.4.3..Thankyou so much

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do this if the helper isn't associated with the block in Magento2:

```
$helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$seoText2 =  $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('seo_text2')->getFrontend()->getValue($block->getProduct());
$attributeCode = 'seo_text2';
echo $helper->productAttribute($_product, $seoText2, $attributeCode);
```